# Xcode Signing & Capabilities "Team" Isn't Retaining Value

Tags: xcode, apple-id

I am trying to run an app on my iPhone and am running into an error: Signing for "MyAppName" requires a development team.

So I set my development team by setting my Signing & Capabilities to "Automatically manage signing" to true. I also go to my Build Settings --> Signing --> Development Team for both debug and release to any SDK.

**The issue is when I go to set "Team" under Signing & Capabilities and drop down to my account...is snaps back to "none". I can see the connected accounts when I drop down but it won't let me select them.**

All of my signing certificates are created but have no status so perhaps this is the issue?

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be a delay. I went back about 4 hours later and was able to select the Team. Not sure how or why but it is working now.